# Function of slot in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have written javascript code to measure monthly retention rate(refferenced http://viget.com/advance/track-visitor-retention-more-deeply-in-google-analytics)
March : `_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Month', 'March2013', 1]);`
April : `_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'Month', 'April2013', 1]);`
But i don't know how google analytics detects the portion of april visitor had visited on march.
What does slot work? if april visitors have visited on march, they have 2 cookies?

Answer (score 1):

You have 5 custom variables in Google Analytics (Standard edition - 50 with premium GA, which is to costly for most companies). The "slot" is simply a numeric index for your variables. If you re-use a slot (within the same scope) that variable will be overwritten with the new value.

In the analytics interface in the audience - > custom -> custom variables section you'll see a line that says

> Primary Dimension: Custom Variable (Key 1)Custom Variable (Key
>   2)Custom Variable (Key 3)Custom Variable (Key 4)Custom Variable (Key
>   5)

"Key1" to "Key5" correspond to your slots - if you click on the links the data table below will show the values for the correspnding slot.

Comment: that's not i want. i wonder that slot's function. **By linked article**, I can measure retention rate if i have written a code such as above. **but, i don't understand how google analytics can detect users who has visited last month before**.

Comment: Google Analytics can't. You have to provide the value for the custom var yourself from your CMS (and btw. this has little to do with slots - they are exactly what I described in my answer).